# Greedy Graph Community Detection in R modMax - why so slow?

Tags: r, performance, graph-algorithm

Trying to detect communities from an adjacency matrix in R:

```
require("modMax")
m = read.csv("matrixfile.csv",headers=FALSE) # matrix is symmetric and mostly contains zeros
m1 = as.matrix(m)
communities = greedy(m1+t(m1)) # add matrix to transpose to make symmetric
```

The CNM algorithm, which this is, claims [near linear time](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0408187) on sparse matrices. Yet I get the following results

```
n       seconds
50      6
75      14
100     27
125     46
2500    11 hours and still not done
```

Note that for the runs that completed, the curve fits O(n^2 log n). Also for the runs completed, each node was assigned to its own community, effectively not clustering the graph at all.

Meanwhile, Python igraph `community_fastgreedy` processes 2500 nodes in under 10 seconds, reducing them to around 13 communities.

Am I somehow using the R package wrong?

Comment: I don't know modMax package... but the igraph package is available in R too... can't you use it ?

Comment: That's definitely a practical answer, I'm just curious about modMax.

Comment: I see... the problem is that you should provide an example of your matrixfile.csv in order to allow us to test why it takes so long...

Comment: http://cf.ac.uk/sdna/wp-content/testmatrix.csv License terms: Census output is Crown copyright and is reproduced with the permission of the Controller of HMSO and the Queen's Printer for Scotland
Source: 2011 SWS MSOA/SOA/Intermediate Zone [Location of usual residence and place of work by sex] - WU01EW - Open

Comment: The algorithm seems completely implemented in R with a lot of loops. Loops are not inherently slow in R, but they're definitely fast in C/C++ and is really easy to write incredibly slow code in R using loops (e.g. if a lot of vector concatenations are performed). So, I guess that the same algorithm would be way faster if it was implemented in C/C++ . `igraph` is written in C/C++ under the hood, that's why is fast.